# Calling c++ clr dll in c# silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, interop, clr

We have a c++ clr application that we have compiled into a dll. We exposed several methods through a managed public ref class in the c++ code. We were actually able to have our native c# application load this dll and pass a system::drawing::bitmap by reference. All we needed to do was add a reference to the dll and all methods were exposed due to implicit pinvoke.
However, as soon as we try to load the dll in our silverlight application, things blow up. Apparently the c++ clr .net libraries used are not compatible with those of silverlight.
We have tried many things, but just can't get silverlight to call our dll.

Please, does anybody have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Anything would be apprciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? I assume from "things blow up" that it doesn't silently fail. ?

Comment: Silverlight itself is not compatible with usual .NET assemlies, but server-side app does. Do you really need to reference your managed c++ assembly from client or I understood something incorrectly?

Comment: When we add a reference to the dll in my silverlight application, we get no methods exposed. After my team mates did some kind of assembly level conversion of the dll to use silverlight libraries instead, we did see exposed functions, but we got some kind of runtime exception when calling one of the exported functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three main options I can think of:

1. Rewrite the logic in the C++/CLR DLL in a Silverlight DLL.  As of Silverlight 5 you can use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560563%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
2. Create a web service that calls your C++/CLR DLL.  The Silverlight app can call a web service and the web service will be able to use the C++/CLR DLL.
3. Expose your C++/CLR DLL as a COM object, install and register it on the Client computer, and use the [COM support in Silverligh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.comautomationfactory%28v=VS.96%29.aspx)t to load the C++/CLR DLL.

Comment: Thanks! We'll try this today and let you know if we get it working.

Comment: We actually ended up compiling the C++/CLR DLL as a native C++ DLL by using a .def file to export native functions. However, we need more testing to see if this will work. The main challenge now is sharing memory (namely, we want the DLL to process an image stored in memory by SilverLight). I am planning to use Marshal.AllocHGlobal() which will hopefully work with SilverLight. **I'll post back more details if we get this working. Please let me know if you have any insight into the memory passing.**

Comment: It worked! We did not even need to use allochglobal(). We were actually directly able to pass the address of the pixel buffer in SilverLight and C++ could access this location.